# Joining parts of equations with lines or arrows

Tags: math-mode, arrows, technical-drawing

I need to add lines or arrows to show the expansion of possibilities as a problem space expand. For example I'm attempting to produce something like this (with the lines added by hand):

[image: equation lines sample]

I can find examples for adding arrows over the top of an equation [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr) and I've started by creating the layout I want using an align block (shown below) and I'm trying to join the sections with arrows as shown in the linked question but I've yet to produce anything useful.

```
\begin{align*}
&&&&(1, 1, 0, 0)&\\
&&(1, 0, 0, 0)&&(1,0,1,0)&\\
0&&(0, 1, 0, 0)&&(1,0,0,1)&\\
&&(0, 0, 1, 0)&&&\\
&&(0, 0, 0, 1)&&&
\end{align*}
```

This feels somewhat crude, can anybody help me complete what I started or suggest a more elegant way (perhaps using a table to store the options and then linking the cells)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple manner to achieve the result is using the TikZ tree construction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sibling distance=20pt,level distance=2.65cm,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
\node {0}
child {node {(0, 0, 0, 1)}}
child {node {(0, 0, 1, 0)}}
child {node {(0, 1, 0, 0)}}
child {node {(1, 0, 0, 0)}
child {node {(1, 0, 0, 1)}}
child {node {(1, 0, 1, 0)}}
child {node {(1, 1, 0, 0)}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Where:

- `grow=right` means that the tree grows in the right direction;
- `sibling distance=20pt` means that the distance between childs is `20pt` (change this to increase or reduce this distance);
- `level distance=2.65cm` represents the distance of the different levels;
- `edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)}` redefines the path from parent nodes to child nodes (to be a straight line); if you don't use this construction, the path is not perfect because some of the connection do not point to the left of the nodes, but to their center.

To have a connection with final arrows, you just have to change:

```
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
```

with:

```
edge from parent path={[-stealth](\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
```

By using the `\tikzmark` macro as the answer you linked, one might proceed as follows:

1. macro definition:

   ```
   % see as reference:
   % use of tikzpicture matrix in align or gather environment
   \def\vertalignmath{\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax}
   \newcommand{\tikzmark}1{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-\vertalignmath] \node [coordinate] (#1){};
   }
   ```

   the use of `\vertalignmath` is to have a correct vertical setting;
2. macro usage within the `align` block:

   ```
   \begin{align*}
   &&&&\tikzmark{d1}(1, 1, 0, 0)&\&&\tikzmark{b1}(1, 0, 0, 0)\tikzmark{c}&&\tikzmark{d2}(1,0,1,0)&\0\tikzmark{a}&&\tikzmark{b2}(0, 1, 0, 0)&&\tikzmark{d3}(1,0,0,1)&\&&\tikzmark{b3}(0, 0, 1, 0)&&&\&&\tikzmark{b4}(0, 0, 0, 1)&&&
   \end{align*}
   ```

   the markers are placed before and after the elements: it is important to give unique names;
3. create the connections; another macro `\connect` is defined:

   ```
   \newcommand{\connect}1{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-\vertalignmath]{
   \foreach \start/\end in {#1}{
     \drawshorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt--(\end);
   }
   }
   }
   ```

   and then used:

   ```
   \connect{a/b1,a/b2,a/b3,a/b4,
   c/d1,c/d2,c/d3}
   ```

   to connect in the right way the markers.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% see as reference:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment#comment126261_59660
\def\vertalignmath{\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-\vertalignmath]\node[coordinate](#1){};
}

\newcommand{\connect}[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-\vertalignmath]{
    \foreach \start/\end in {#1}{
      \draw[shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt](\start)--(\end);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&&&&\tikzmark{d1}(1, 1, 0, 0)&\\
&&\tikzmark{b1}(1, 0, 0, 0)\tikzmark{c}&&\tikzmark{d2}(1,0,1,0)&\\
0\tikzmark{a}&&\tikzmark{b2}(0, 1, 0, 0)&&\tikzmark{d3}(1,0,0,1)&\\
&&\tikzmark{b3}(0, 0, 1, 0)&&&\\
&&\tikzmark{b4}(0, 0, 0, 1)&&&
\end{align*}
\connect{a/b1,a/b2,a/b3,a/b4,
c/d1,c/d2,c/d3} 
\end{document}
```

The result, after at least two compilation runs, is:

[image]

In order to have arrows, the `\connect` macro can be changed into:

```
\newcommand{\connect}[2][-]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-\vertalignmath]{
    \foreach \start/\end in {#2}{
      \draw[#1,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt](\start)--(\end);
    }
  }
}
```

Then the use of:

```
\connect[-stealth]{a/b1,a/b2,a/b3,a/b4,
c/d1,c/d2,c/d3}
```

will generates:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is astoundingly detailed given you took 20 minutes. I'll wait a while to give others a chance to reply but at the moment I intend to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks :) Notice that I'm going to add another possibility, easier IMHO, to do the same job via the tree construction with TikZ.

Comment: How is the solution if two nodes have childs?

Comment: @jpayansomet: do you mean with the first method? You can try to augment the sibling distance.. but I'm not sure having got the point. Could you elaborate better?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: For example: if the first and the second nodes have child nodes, the representation will be hatched. If you want, I can put an example.

Comment: @jpayansomet: so probably I got it `:)`. This is a common problem in setting trees; see for reference [How to modify the distance between branches when drawing trees using TiKZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25745/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: with the later reference, I think the solution is better. I vote up