# how to write a formula that branches into two?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, amsmath

I would like to write a formula (see the picture), how can i fix the arrows?

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\linespread{1.5}

\frenchspacing 

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}

\usepackage{multicol}




\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}


$ \dfrac{a \pm b}{c} = \rightarrow  $

$ \dfrac{a+b}{c} $

$ \dfrac{a-b}{c} $




\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I ask a favour please? Thank you to have accepted (check) my answer, but for my opinion is not the best. Good year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another simple possibility using [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={minimum height=-2cm,minimum width=1cm}},column sep=3em,row sep=-7pt]
 & \dfrac{a+b}{c}  \\
\dfrac{a \pm b}{c} = \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] &  \\
 & \dfrac{a-b}{c} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is an adapted version from [Claudio Fiandrino's answer to Joining parts of equations with lines or arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106529/134144) using `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, 
                    sibling distance=50pt,
                    level distance=2cm,
                    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
                    edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex}]
    \node {$ \dfrac{a \pm b}{c} =$}
    child {node {$ \dfrac{a-b}{c} $}}
    child {node {$ \dfrac{a+b}{c} $}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ryuk: From the message you quoted, I guess that you copied my code into an existing document that was previously compiled and had used `\usepackage[italian]{babel}`. To get rid of the error, either recompile or add the above mentioned package back to your preamble.

Answer (score 8):

Without using a hammersledge to crack a nut, you already have the necessary packages for the below code.

*Unrelated*: `epsfigure` and `anysize` are obsolete. The functionalities of the former are achieved with `graphicx` and  the latter can be replaced with `geometry`  (which you use, anyway).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\linespread{1.5}
\frenchspacing

\usepackage{old-arrows}

\begin{document}


\[ \dfrac{a \pm b}{c} =
\begin{matrix}
\nearrow \\[-1.5ex] \searrow
\end{matrix}
\:
\begin{matrix}
 \dfrac{a+b}{c} \\[3ex]
 \dfrac{a-b}{c}
\end{matrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have the arrows figure centred on the math axis, and control the gap between the arrows, you can replace the `matrix` environment for the arrows with `\Vectorstack` from the `stackengine` package (load it with option `[usestackEOL]`). Here are two examples, with a different gap:

```
\[\Lstackgap = 10pt\dfrac{a ± b}{c} =
\Vectorstack{%
\nearrow \\%[-1.5ex]
 \searrow }
\:
\begin{matrix}
 \dfrac{a+b}{c} \\[3ex]
 \dfrac{a-b}{c}
\end{matrix} \]

\[\Lstackgap = 18pt\dfrac{a ± b}{c} =
\Vectorstack{%
\nearrow \\%[-1.5ex]
 \searrow }
\:
\begin{matrix}
 \dfrac{a+b}{c} \\[3ex]
 \dfrac{a-b}{c}
\end{matrix} \]
```

[image]

Comment: Those arrows look uncentered in relation to the equals sign. Would there be any way of fixing that?

Comment: Do you mean *vertically* uncentred?

Comment: Yes, I mean vertically uncentered. The arrows' origins are lower than I visually expect them to be.

Comment: @AJFarmar: I've posted a variant code, which uses `stackengine` and is more versatile. Please see if it's OK for you.

Comment: The visual improvement is enormous. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. We're here to help, as much as we can.

Comment: @Bernard Good and happy new year. Can you edit your answer. There are two fragments without `.'...'.`

Comment: @Sebastiano: I wish you a very happy new year too. As often, I forgot to check if all the code was in the right position. Thank you for pointing it!